# SWTBot: Press "F5" on project in package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, swtbot

I'm currently trying to press the <kbd>F5</kbd> keybinding using SWTBot tests to refresh a project in the package explorer. So far, I have been unsuccessful.

When I attempt to press the <kbd>F5</kbd> keybinding in a way such as this:

```java
SWTBotView packageExplorer = getPackageExplorer();
SWTBotTree tree = packageExplorer.bot().tree();
SWTBotTreeItem treeItem = tree.getTreeItem("newProject");
treeItem.select();
treeItem.pressShortcut(0, SWT.F5, (char) 0);
```

I receive the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.keyboard.Keyboard.pressShortcut(Keyboard.java:138)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.AbstractSWTBot.pressShortcut(AbstractSWTBot.java:862)
at org.eclipse.project.ui.wizard.project.RefreshUiTest.performDefaultEclipseRefresh(RefreshUiTest.java:43)
at org.eclipse.project.ui.wizard.project.RefreshUiTest.defaultEclipseBehaviourIsNotHindered(RefreshUiTest.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.junit.SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner.run(SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner.java:54)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.PlatformUITestHarness$1.run(PlatformUITestHarness.java:47)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3717)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3366)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:54)
at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EN_CA.keyboard not found, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Keyboard_Layouts for more information.
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.keyboard.KeyboardLayout.getKeyboardLayout(KeyboardLayout.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.keyboard.KeyboardLayout.getDefaultKeyboardLayout(KeyboardLayout.java:75)
at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.keyboard.Keystrokes.<clinit>(Keystrokes.java:110)
... 61 more
```

I've also tried using:

```
Keyboard key = KeyboardFactory.getSWTKeyboard();
key.pressShortcut(Keystrokes.F5);
```

but it has failed with a nearly identical stacktrace.

How can I simulate pressing the <kbd>F5</kbd> key on a project in the package explorer using SWTBot tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause indicates that `EN_CA.keyboard not found`. SWTBot does not come with a predefined `EN_CA` keyboard layout.

If it fits your needs you can use the `EN_US` keyboard layout like this

```
SWTBotPreferences.KEYBOARD_LAYOUT = "EN_US";
```

Or define your own keyboard layout as desribed here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Keyboard_Layouts